# Index multiple vectors into table in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have three vectors:

```
position <- c(13, 13, 24, 20, 24, 6, 13)
my_string_allele <- c("T>A", "T>A", "G>C", "C>A", "A>G", "A>G", "G>T")
position_ref <- c("12006", "1108", "13807", "1970", "9030", "2222", "4434")
```

I want to create a table (starting from the smallest position) as shown below. I want to account for the number of occurrence for each `my_string_allele` column for each position and have their corresponding position_ref in `position_ref` column. What would be the simplest way to do this?

```
position    T>A position_ref    G>C position_ref    C>A position_ref    A>G position_ref    G>T position_ref
6                                                                       1   2222        
13          2   12006, 1108                                                                 1   4434
20                                                  1   1970                
24                               1  13807                               1   9030
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `spread()` method which stretches data to the wide format with `mutate_all()` to count the number of occurrences.

**Data**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(position, my_string_allele, position_ref, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Code**

```
df %>% group_by(position, my_string_allele) %>%
  mutate(position_ref = paste(position_ref, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  spread(my_string_allele, position_ref) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(N = if_else(is.na(.), NA_integer_, lengths(str_split(., ", ")))))
```

**Output**

```
  position `A>G` `C>A` `G>C` `G>T` `T>A`       `A>G_N` `C>A_N` `G>C_N` `G>T_N` `T>A_N`
     <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>         <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1        6 2222  NA    NA    NA    NA                1      NA      NA      NA      NA
2       13 NA    NA    NA    4434  12006, 1108      NA      NA      NA       1       2
3       20 NA    1970  NA    NA    NA               NA       1      NA      NA      NA
4       24 9030  NA    13807 NA    NA                1      NA       1      NA      NA
```

(You can sort the columns by their column names to get the output you show in the question.)

Comment: Thanks, but would be nice to also have number of occurence in the table.

Comment: @MAPK I'm not sure whether the number of occurrences should be in the same column or be separate columns. The former can be achieved easily by @JdeMello's method(use `paste(n(), xxx)`), but the latter will be a little hard.

Comment: I try to do it use separate columns, please see the edit.

Comment: @MAPK Sorry for editing again. The original code is cumbersome and unreadable, I use a concise way with `mutate_all()`.

Comment: I am having problem with the output when I use large data. How do you get the output in dataframe format?

Comment: @MAPK if your input is a data frame, the output will still be a data frame. The first object `df` of my code is made by `df <- data.frame(position, my_string_allele, position_ref, stringsAsFactors = F)`.

Comment: Could you please explain this bit?  `mutate_all(funs(N = if_else(is.na(.), NA_integer_, lengths(str_split(., ", ")))))`

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: I am adapting part of @DarrenTsai's answer with `data.table` to provide the number of occurrence as well (since it is missing from his answer). Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(position, my_string_allele, position_ref, stringsAsFactors = F)

setDT(df)

df[, `:=`(position_ref = paste(.N, paste(position_ref, collapse = ", "))),
    by = c("position", "my_string_allele")] %>% 
  unique(., by = c("position", "my_string_allele", "position_ref")) %>% 
  dcast(position ~ my_string_allele, value.var = "position_ref")
```

Result:

```
   position    A>G    C>A     G>C    G>T           T>A
1:        6 1 2222   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>          <NA>
2:       13   <NA>   <NA>    <NA> 1 4434 2 12006, 1108
3:       20   <NA> 1 1970    <NA>   <NA>          <NA>
4:       24 1 9030   <NA> 1 13807   <NA>          <NA>
```

With `dplyr` (largely based on @DarrenTsai's answer, should upvote his as well):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(position, my_string_allele) %>%
  mutate(position_ref = paste(n(), paste(position_ref, collapse = ", "))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  tidyr::spread(my_string_allele, position_ref)
```